# Atom using System Proxy

Tags: proxy, atom-editor

Regardless of what I configure in .apmrc, ATOM is using my system proxy settings for connection. Only when I change the proxy under Internet Options to my CNTLM service does it actually do so. How can I fix this issue?

```
Userconfig: \.atom\.apmrc   
http-proxy = "http://localhost:3128"  
https-proxy = "http://localhost:3128"  
proxy = "http://localhost:3128"  
strict-ssl = false  


atom --version
Atom    : 1.30.0    
Electron: 2.0.5    
Chrome  : 61.0.3163.100   
Node    : 8.9.3   

apm --version   
apm  1.19.0   
npm  3.10.10   
node 6.9.5 x64   
atom 1.30.0   
python 3.7.0   
git   
visual studio 2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply modified .apmrc file, it would be reset every time when you reboot atom.

See https://github.com/atom/apm#behind-a-firewall , you'll find solution to this under the 'Using a proxy?' part.

And then run `cmd`

`apm config set strict-ssl false
apm config set https-proxy https://$Your_proxy`

P.S.
Normally it'll be fixed, but if a problem like SSL782 pops up,
See

[Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:782](https://github.com/jspm/github/issues/59)

Answer (score 1):

## ATOM PROXY LAUNCHER

If you are under Linux operating system, you can call a script:

```
./atom-proxy-launcher.sh
```

by first creating the script `atom-proxy-launcher` that contains the following commands:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
PROXY_IP=192.168.1.100:8888 # change to your proxy address
apm config set proxy $PROXY_IP
apm config set http-proxy $PROXY_IP
HTTP_PROXY="http://"$PROXY_IP \
HTTPS_PROXY="http://"$PROXY_IP \
atom --proxy-server="http://"$PROXY_IP
```

---

save the file, name it `atom-proxy-launcher.sh` and change its permission into executable:

```
chmod +x atom-proxy-launcher.sh
./atom-proxy-launcher.sh
```

This way you can simplify the complex setting and make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is where I need to get this working next!